# wordpress login redirect function

Tags: wordpress, function, redirect, authentication

I am trying to create my own plugin in wordpress. Everything works great but I want to make a loginredirect check for users who want to access to the plugins page.

Here is my function in my `functions.php`:

```
function wpuf_auth_redirect_login() {  
    $user = wp_get_current_user();  
    if ( $user->id == 0 ) {  
        nocache_headers();  
        wp_redirect(get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));  
        exit();
    }  
}
```

And this is from my `myplugin.php`:

```
function wpuf_user_edit_profile() {  
    wpuf_auth_redirect_login(); // if not logged in, redirect to login page
    nocache_headers();  
    wpuf_post_form_style();  
    wpuf_user_edit_profile_form();  
} 

add_shortcode('wpuf_editprofile', 'wpuf_user_edit_profile');
```

It is not working. If I enter the plugins page as a guest in browser it does not redirect. It only shows the template uncomplete. Any help?

Comment: try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com . They tend to be better about answering WP api questions. SO is better at the programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

Where you say that it 'only shows the template uncomplete', this could indicate that there is a syntax error in your PHP code, and the server has stopped rendering the page at the point of that error.

I would suggest that you check for any errors by turning error reporting on, and seeing what happens from there.